# Domain user removed from local administrator group in Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, window

I have computer with Windows 7 Enterprise Edition. I added my domain user account to local administrator group. it works for some time. however, once I restart the machine, In notice the domain user is no longer in administrator group & I have to redo it again.

is there away to make my domain user in the local administrator group forever.

Comment: What OS is your domain controller?

Comment: Windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: There may be a GPO preventing you from doing that.